# I need help in CodeIgniter , get data from database

Tags: php, database, codeigniter, frameworks

I have 3 table : users , posts  , category

category : id , name

```
1 linux
2 Mac
```

users : id , name , email , image

```
1  Jak    t@t.com    afs
2  Stif   t2@t.com    122afs
```

posts : id , idc , idu , title , content

If I use getall function

```
function getall(){
   $this->db->limit(10);
   $this->db->order_by("id", "desc"); 
   $query = $this->db->get('posts');
   $res=$query->result();
   return $query->result();
   }
```

then result like this

```
 - 1  1  2  test   content1
 - 2  1  1  test2   content2
```

but I need get result like this :

```
 - 1  linux  Stif   test   content1
 - 2  linux  Jak    test2   content2
```

How do I do that?

Comment: Why do you assign $query->result() to a variable and then return $query->result(); There's no point in assigning it to a variable if you aren't going to use the variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

with `join` you can make the query that you want
try this:

```
function getall(){
   $this->db->select('*, category.id as category_id, users.id as user_id');
   $this->db->from("posts");
   $this->db->join("users", "users.id = posts.idu");
   $this->db->join("category", "category.id = posts.idc"); 
   $this->db->order_by("posts.id", "desc"); 
   $this->db->limit(10);
   $query = $this->db->get();
   $res=$query->result();
   return $query->result();
```

}

Comment: Error Number: 1052

Column 'id' in order clause is ambiguous

SELECT * FROM (`posts`) JOIN `users` ON `users`.`id` = `posts`.`idu` JOIN `category` ON `category`.`id` = `posts`.`idc` ORDER BY `id` desc LIMIT 10

Filename: C:\AppServ\www\ci\system\database\DB_driver.php

Comment: edit again. if does't work, try to print the query after $re="$query->result(); insert echo($this->db->last_query()); @MHDSY